# jObjectArray has not been declared

Tags: c++, java-native-interface

In my function, i am trying to get the size of a String array that has been passed to a C++ class through JNI, but i keep getting the error: "jobjectarray has not been declared". here is my C++:

```
int targetCount = 0;
    JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
    Java_com_example_processArray(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jobjectarray targetsArray){
        targetCount = env->GetArrayLenght(env, targetsArray);
    }
```

Not sure how to go about this because i thought it uses the Array already passed directly. Solutions greatly appreciated as always. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use javah to create your jni signatures.  `jobjectarray` is not correct, the correct syntax is `jobjectArray`

See [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp17314)